# Example newsletter dialog close character is NULL (HEX 0)

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter, popups

When logged in we sometimes see this in the right side of a page on Stack Exchange site: (Meta also)

> [image]

Clicking the "example newsletter" opens it in a pop over window aka dialog: (taken with Chrome)

> [image]

That weird character is actually just NULL (ASCII/HEX value 0) so the browser is replacing with something of its choice.

> [image]

Observed in other Stack Exchange sites as well so it's not site specific.

Comment: [Seems to be a NUL character](http://i.imgur.com/gVQmdBy.png) (unless browser dev tools mess that up)

Comment: @Stijn oh that's nasty! Will update the post, after some reading I understand that REPLACEMENT CHARACTER is actually something injected by the browser itself.

Comment: By other sites, do you mean other Stack exchange sites or _other sites_?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Stack Exchange, thought it was obvious but guess it's not. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd figured, but just checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should've been the × symbol.

Fixed in the next build that gets out; 2013.12.9.1736 for meta and 2013.12.9.1209 for sites.

Comment: Thanks☺highly☺appreciated!